# gnuplot for cycle and spaces in filename

Tags: bash, filenames, gnuplot

I have small script in bash, which is generating graphs via gnuplot. 
Everything works fine until names of input files contain space(s).

Here's what i've got:

```
INPUTFILES=("data1.txt" "data2 with spaces.txt" "data3.txt")

...

#MAXROWS is set earlier, not relevant.


for LINE in $( seq 0 $(( MAXROWS - 1 )) );do

gnuplot << EOF
reset
set terminal png
set output "out/graf_${LINE}.png"

filenames="${INPUTFILES[@]}"

set multiplot 

plot for [file in filenames] file every ::0::${LINE} using 1:2 with line title "graf_${LINE}"

unset multiplot
EOF
done
```

This code works, but only without spaces in names of input files.

In the example gnuplot evaluate this:

```
1 iteration: file=data1.txt  - CORRECT
2 iteration: file=data2  - INCORRECT
3 iteration: file=with  - INCORRECT
4 iteration: file=spaces.txt  - INCORRECT
```

Comment: Don't use `seq`. `for ((line=0; line < maxrows; line++)); do`. Don't use all-caps variable names. Think you worded the question incorrectly unless for some reason things really do break when filenames do **NOT** contain spaces. There is no quote removal within a heredoc. "${INPUTFILES[@]}" expands to a space-separated list of elements surrounded by double quotes. If that works in gnuplot for specifying a list of files, you'd have to figure out how to escape spaces.

Comment: @ormaaj Fixed question. I had in mind some system calls from gnuplot .. like sed to switch spaces to dashes and then again back.

And why not use seq ( readability ?! ) and all-caps variable names ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is that you can't do exactly what you want to do.  Gnuplot splits the string in an iteration on spaces and there's no way around that (AFIK).  Depending on what you want, there may be a "Work-around".  You can write a (recursive) function in gnuplot to replace a character string with another --

```
#S,C & R stand for STRING, CHARS and REPLACEMENT to help this be a little more legible.
replace(S,C,R)=(strstrt(S,C)) ? \
    replace( S[:strstrt(S,C)-1].R.S[strstrt(S,C)+strlen(C):] ,C,R) : S
```

Bonus points to anyone who can figure out how to do this without recursion...

Then your (bash) loop looks something like:

```
INPUTFILES_BEFORE=("data1.txt" "data2 with spaces.txt" "data3.txt")
INPUTFILES=()
#C style loop to avoid changing IFS -- Sorry SO doesn't like the #...
#This loop pre-processes files and changes spaces to '#_#'
for (( i=0; i < ${#INPUTFILES_BEFORE[@]}; i++)); do 
    FILE=${INPUTFILES_BEFORE[${i}]}
    INPUTFILES+=( "`echo ${FILE} | sed -e 's/ /#_#/g'`" ) #replace ' ' with '#_#'
done
```

which preprocesses your input files to add '#_#' to the filenames which have spaces in them...  Finally, the "complete" script:

```
...

INPUTFILES_BEFORE=("data1.txt" "data2 with spaces.txt" "data3.txt")
INPUTFILES=()
for (( i=0; i < ${#INPUTFILES_BEFORE[@]}; i++)); do 
    FILE=${INPUTFILES_BEFORE[${i}]}
    INPUTFILES+=( "`echo ${FILE} | sed -e 's/ /#_#/g'`" ) #replace ' ' with '#_#'
done

for LINE in $( seq 0 $(( MAXROWS - 1 )) );do
gnuplot <<EOF
filenames="${INPUTFILES[@]}"
replace(S,C,R)=(strstrt(S,C)) ? \
        replace( S[:strstrt(S,C)-1].R.S[strstrt(S,C)+strlen(C):] , C ,R) : S
#replace '#_#' with ' ' in filenames.
plot for [file in filenames] replace(file,'#_#',' ') every ::0::${LINE} using 1:2 with line title "graf_${LINE}"

EOF
done
```

However, I think the take-away here is that you shouldn't use spaces in filenames ;)

Comment: Yes, that's it. I've almost done unthinkable and implemented solution with tmp files (copies of originals, but names without spaces) :) Thanks!

Comment: @Rob -- Good catch on the edit.  This one was a pretty fun little challenge for me.  Thanks

Comment: @mgilson, for fun and completeness... a non-recursive replace function at the cost of using three variables (`RPs`,`RPi`,`i`).
`replaceStr(s,s1,s2) = (RPs="", RPi=1, (sum[i=1:strlen(s)] ((s[RPi:RPi+strlen(s1)-1] eq s1 ? (RPs=RPs.s2, RPi=RPi+strlen(s1)) : (RPs=RPs.s[RPi:RPi], RPi=RPi+1)), 0)), RPs)`

Answer (score 0):

Escape the spaces:

```
"data2\ with\ spaces.txt"
```

**EDIT**

It seems that even with escape sequences, as you have mentioned, the bash `for` will always parse the input on the spaces.

Can you convert your script to work in a `while` loop fashion:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=83424

This also may be a solution, but it's new to me and I'm still playing with it to understand exactly what it's doing:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html

Comment: This doesn't help. As you can see, my INPUTFILES are in ""

Comment: The problem comes in gnuplot "for cycle" evaluation. Gnuplot doesn't care about "" at all.

Comment: I am familiar with bash IFS variable, **but** this problem is about "**gnuplot** for cycle evaluation".